# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation being called BEFORE viewWillAppear

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, viewdidappear

I just tracked down a crash I was having in my iOS app and it is related to willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation being called before viewWillAppear.

I have an app with two views. Basically, when view1 disappears, I release some arrays, assuming they will be re-initialized when it re-appears in viewWillAppear.

However, if I change orientation in view2 then switch back to view1, this causes willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation to happen before view1 has calledviewWillAppear and re-initialized everything and this causes a crash.

Is there any way to delay willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation until after the view has appeared and everything has been re-initialized?

If not, the only solutions I can see are either not using willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation (which results in an ugly looking orientation change) or not releasing my data when I switch from view1 to view2 which results in more memory being used than necessary.

Does anybody have any thoughts on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy-loading style code avoid your problem, like:

```
NSArray* someData;


-(void)somefun1{

   if (!someData) {

      [self loadData];
   }

    //use your data
}

-(void)somefun2{

    if (!someData) {

    [self loadData];
    }

    //use your data

}

-(void)loadData{
    //some loading code
}
```

use lazy-loading style code you never need mind event calling order.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but how can I tell if my array has been re-initialized or not? I tried if (!myArray) and if (myArray=nil) and if ([myArray count]==0) but none of these seem to work after the array has been released and before it has been redefined. 

The array was defined in @interface because it's scope is supposed to be the entire class, then it is initialized in viewDidAppar, then released in viewWillDissappear. Now in the case of this orientation change I need to find a way to tell whether it has been released or not. A global boolean could work but that's not very elegant.

Comment: Ok I have an idea. Should I be releasing and THEN setting my data array to nil, so I can later check if it is equal to nil, otherwise reinitialize it?